# setTimeout after clicks - how to get only last iteration

Tags: jquery, ajax, settimeout

Heloo, I'm getting tired how to call ajax using my product counter on shopping cart.

I created simple example here: https://jsfiddle.net/s77j79nn/7/

The problem is when I want pass from quantity "1" to qunatity ex. "7" Im getting 6 alerts in document window, that equals 6 ajax requests. I hoped setting timeout will solve that problem, but nope.

I want to get only last quantity variale after 2-3 seconds, if someone on site will check quantity from 1 to 8 his browser call only one request to database.

Can someone resolve my problem? Thanks!

```
$(".iteration").on("click", function() {

  var quantity = $(".cart-product .counter-label").text(); 
  var pricee = $(".single-price").text();  

  if( $(this).hasClass("plus") ) {
    if ( quantity != 9 ) {
      quantity++;
      $(this).parent().find(".counter-label").text(quantity);

      setTimeout(function(){

        // CALL AJAX HERE

        $(".price-value").text((quantity * pricee).toFixed(2));
        alert(quantity);
      },2000);    
    }  
  }
  if( $(this).hasClass("minus") ) {
    if ( quantity != 1 ) {
        quantity--;
        $(this).parent().find(".counter-label").text(quantity);
    }
  } 
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store timeout ID, and cancel it if you press the plus button again. Something like this:

```
clearTimeout(timeout);  
timeout = setTimeout(function(){...}, 2000);
```

Here's your [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s77j79nn/8/) after including the above change.